# How do I run Kruskal and post HOC on multiple variables in R?

Tags: r, loops, formula, anova

Please excuse me if I have not formated my code correctly as I am new to the site. I also do not know how to provide sample data properly.

I have a data set of 42 obs. and 37 variables (first column being the group, 3 groups) of non normal distributed data; I want to compare all of my 36 parameters between the 3 groups and do a subsequent post hoc (pairwise.wilcox?).

The data are flow cell counts for three different patient groups. I have been able to  perform the initial comparison creating a formula and running an aov (though I would like to do Kruskal) but have not found a way to perform the post hoc to all variables in the same way.

```
#Data
    Type   Neutrophils  Monocytes   NKC .....
    ------------------------------------------
    IN       546          2663      545
    IN       0797         7979      008
    OUT      0899         3899      345
    OUT      6868         44533     689
    HC       9898         43443     563


#Cbind all variable together to run model on all
    formula <- as.formula(paste0("cbind(", paste(names(LessCount)[-1], 
       collapse = ","), ") ~ Type"))
    print(formula)

#Run test on model
    fit <- aov(formula, data=LessCount)

#Print results
    summary(fit)

 Response Neutrophils :
            Df    Sum Sq Mean Sq F value Pr(>F)
Type         2  18173966 9086983  1.8099 0.1771
Residuals   39 195806220 5020672               

 Response Monocytes :
            Df   Sum Sq Mean Sq F value Pr(>F)
Type         2   694945  347472  0.7131 0.4964
Residuals   39 19004809  487303               

 Response Mono.Classic :
            Df   Sum Sq Mean Sq F value  Pr(>F)  
Type         2  1561778  780889  2.5842 0.08833 .
Residuals   39 11785116  302182  

###export anova####
    capture.output(summary(fit),file="test1.csv")

#If Significant,Check which# (currently doing by hand individually)
    pairwise.wilcox.test(LessCount$pDCs, LessCount$Type,
                     p.adjust.method = "BH")
```

I get out a table the results for the aov for every variable in my console, but would like to do the same for the post hoc, since I need every p value.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you can directly use the function `kruskal.test()` and get the p.values.

Here is an example with the iris dataset. I use the function `apply()` in order to apply the kruskal.test function to each variable (except Species, which is the variable with group information).

```
data(iris)
apply(iris[-5], 2, function(x) kruskal.test(x = x, g = iris$Species)$p.value)

# Sepal.Length  Sepal.Width Petal.Length  Petal.Width 
# 8.918734e-22 1.569282e-14 4.803974e-29 3.261796e-29
```

Comment: That is incredibly useful, thank you so much! How can I then do the same for the pairwise wilcox test so that I can get out the p values to find out between which groups the difference is (I'll need all of the p values for all of the variables between all the groups, n=3)?

Comment: Also, what does the 2 after [,-5] indicate?

Comment: `apply()` will apply a function an each column, so I remove the 5th column (`Species`) because it is not a numeric variable. Don't forget to accept the answer if it helped you. About wilcox test, do you know if there is an existing function ?

Comment: Sorry, yes, I know the purpose of taking out the categorical column, I was asking about the "2" that follows it, right before "function(x)". And thank you! Tried to up vote but do not have enough credit yet; I accepted it. I am using the following for the wilcox:     pairwise.wilcox.test(LessCount$pDCs, 
     LessCount$Type, p.adjust.method = "BH"), with data = LessCount and Type serving as my "species"

Comment: the second argument of `apply()` : 1 if you want to apply the function per row, 2 if you want per column.

Comment: All clear on     apply(), thank you for clarifying!

Comment: I just got it to work in the same manner for the wilcox, thank you so much for your help!

Comment: You might find the `Dunn.test` function in the `DescTools` package to be helpful for similar problems. The package includes helpful tools for plotting and non-parametric statistical tests.